# O_EXLOCK vs flock()

Tags: c++, file, unix, file-io, locking

What is the difference between calling `open()` with the `O_EXLOCK` flag versus calling just calling `open()` and then calling `flock()`? The latter has a potential race condition, but other than that both ways gets an exclusive process lock on a file, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is atomicity: `open()` with `O_EXLOCK` is atomic, whereas `open()` followed by `flock()` are two distinct operations.

Comment: Is `O_EXLOCK` only supported on UNIX and not on Linux? I see that OS X also supports it.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: If I am not mistaken, it's a BSD thing.